# JavaScript drawImage load issues when using variable parameters

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm following the code tutorials from 'Making Isometric Real-Time Games with HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript'. Unfortunately, the code seems to have issues with drawing images with variables as parameters.

```
  var logoImg = new Image();

  // We want to resent the image so that it fills 50% of the browser window 
  // while maintaining its width/height aspect ratio
  var originalWidth = logoImg.width;
  logoImg.width = Math.round((50 * document.body.clientWidth) / 100);
  logoImg.height = Math.round((logoImg.width * logoImg.height) / originalWidth);

  var logo = {
    img: logoImg,
    x: (canvas.width/2) - (logoImg.width/2),
    y: (canvas.height/2) - (logoImg.height/2)
  }

  logoImg.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(logo.img, logo.x, logo.y, logo.img.width, logo.img.height);
  }

  logoImg.src = 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

Replacing

```
ctx.drawImage(logo.img, logo.x, logo.y, logo.img.width, logo.img.height);
```

with

```
ctx.drawImage(logoImg, 1, 1, 100, 100);
```

fixes the issue. Am I right in thinking that because the onload() function is called before the variables have been calculated, that it's not loading correctly? If so, how do I load the image correctly using those variables? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `ctx.drawImage(logoImg, 1, 1, 100, 100);` this solved the problem just because you set manually the dimension. The main problem is here:

```
var originalWidth = logoImg.width;
```

You haven't yet `logoImg.width` or `height` because the image is not still loaded.

Here the complete corrected example ([here a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/k353o6e9/)):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var logoImg = new Image();

var logo = {
    img: logoImg,
    x: (canvas.width/2) - (logoImg.width/2),
    y: (canvas.height/2) - (logoImg.height/2)
}

logoImg.onload = function () {
    var originalWidth = logoImg.width;
    logoImg.width = Math.round((50 * document.body.clientWidth) / 100);
    logoImg.height = Math.round((logoImg.width * logoImg.height) / originalWidth);
    //debugger;
    ctx.drawImage(logo.img, logo.x, logo.y, logo.img.width, logo.img.height);
}

logoImg.src = 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```